# Analytical approximation for an integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^4 + a^2t^4 - 2at^2x^2\cos(x) + a^2t^2x^2 - 2atx^3\sin(x)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximation, approximate-integration

I am looking for an approximation/solution to this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^4 + a^2t^4 - 2at^2x^2\cos(x) + a^2t^2x^2 - 2atx^3\sin(x)}.$$

Particularly, I'm looking for the case that $a>0$ and $t>0$.

Comment: any chance that one (or both) of the paramters is particulary big or small

Comment: A solution exists for the case that $t=0$. But $a$ and $t$ cannot be large. In fact $a<f(t)$, for some decreasing function $f$.

Comment: so an expansion $a \rightarrow 0_+$ would be a valid option?

Comment: Yes! It would've been more preferable if the solution would've approached infinity as $a \to f(\tau)_-$ .

Comment: Can this be done by residues?

Comment: Assume that $a, t > 0$ and write $a = \tan \alpha \sin \alpha$ for a unique $\alpha \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. Then $$t_0 := \frac{\alpha}{\tan \alpha}$$ is the smallest positive $t$ for which the integral diverges.